# Moving Icons from one page to another in the Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

As a programmer I have a tonne of icons pinned to my Task Bar (Visual Studios / 5 Different Browsers / Etc...)

When you reach enough icons to fill the bar it flips the rest onto a 2nd page that they let you scroll through with a little scrollbar.

You can easily re-order anything on any given page by dragging the icon but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get something to go from page 1 to page 2 without putting it at the front of page 2 and closing something on page 1.

This is problematic and I'd be surprised if there isn't a way to do this normally.

Comment: With that many icons to look through it might be faster to search in the Start Menu. Just press the Windows key and type a part of what you want to run. For example searching for "p a f" is a lot faster than navigating Control Panel -> Programs and Features.

Comment: @Ampersand The issue isn't opening programs. I only have about 1/2 the bar pinned, mainly so the things i use the most are on page 1, and things that are secondary are on the 2nd+ page(s). I'm looking to move something that's **already open** onto the 1/2 of page 1 that's not pinned so i can access it readily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: Unlock the Task bar and pull it up to create two rows. Now you can drag pinned apps from "page 2" to "page 1" and reorder the way you want. Once done, re-size task bar to original size. Not the perfect solution, but it works.

Comment: Ooh! didn't think of this! Works Great for taskbars on top/bottom of the screen but not on the side. I like it though, and it does the job! Thankyou!